# Render animation stops after rendering the first frame

Tags: rendering, animation

instead of rendering the 20 frames of the animation it only renders the first one and stops as if it was a "render frame" and not a "render Animation"(ctrl F12) process
this only happens in this project file and new projects render just fine
i reduced the blend file to reproduce the error. thanks a lot.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ffzmnXGHPg444HA3ifM3tBQMNCM0y8we/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello, that's weird it works fine for me, have you tried with another Blender version?

Comment: Well there's no object to render there, but having set up all the file paths I got 100 files produced as expected without any other changes.

Comment: i tried blender version 3.3.1 and 3.2.1 both resulted in the same problem

Answer (score 1):

i had copied the user preferences from my older computer in which the render directory in the settings was Drive F:/ . and this partition doesnt exist in my new computer. changing the output directory from preferences and "output properties" tab solved the issue. thank you everyone your comments helped a lot.